# Unknown devices on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I noticed that I have unknown devices in my Device Manager on Windows 10 machine:

[image]

Where do they appear from? What to do with them?

**EDIT1:**

Device by connection view:

[image]

Device instance path and hardware ids:

ROOT\NET\0001
ptun0901

ROOT\NET\0002
ptun0901

ROOT\NET\0003
ptun0901

...

**EDIT2:**

My mainboard is Gigabyte Z390 AORUS PRO.
Installed the following from CD:

```
Intel(R) Management Engine Software(300 Series) Install Driver 

Intel(R) HECI Device Driver You MUST install this driver to ensure proper system operation. 
Version:1846.12.0.1177 
Size:69.40MB 


INF Update Utility(300 Series) Install Driver 

For Intel 300 Series Chipset 
Version:10.1.17968.8131 
Size:4.48MB 


Intel(R) HD Graphics Driver Install Driver 

Intel(R) Iris(R) Plus Graphics, Intel(R) Iris(R) Pro Graphics, Intel(R) HD Graphics and Intel(R) UHD Graphics on 6th Gen/7th Gen/8th Gen/Apollo Lake/Gemini Lake  
Version:25.20.100.6617 
Size:1025.06MB 


Intel Rapid Storage Technology driver Install Driver 

Intel driver for AHCI and RAID mode. 
Version:17.2.6.1027 
Size:21.22MB 


Realtek High Definition Audio Driver(300 SER) Install Driver 

Realtek High Definition Audio Driver 
Version:6.0.1.8586 
Size:62.13MB 


Intel(R) Network Connections Software Install Driver 

This release includes software and drivers for Intel(R) PRO/100 
Version:23.5 
Size:252.77MB 


Intel Serial IO Driver Install Driver 

Fro Intel Chepset Serial IO device on Win 10 
Version:30.100.1902.3 
Size:2.29MB
```

**EDIT3:**

I uninstalled all unknown devices and will try to reboot:

[image]

but unknown device did not disappear.

Comment: This is usually something from the motherboard. Did you download related drivers from all your manufacturers?

Comment: Do you have an app from the computer manufacturer to update drivers?  Update all drivers, restart and remove non-working drivers.

Comment: Can you show where they appear in the "View → Show by connection" view?

Comment: @user1686 see EDIT1

Comment: Please provide, from the devices’ _Detail_ properties page, the _Device instance path_ and _Hardware IDs_. The _Value_ panel supports copying. You don’t have to do this for all of the devices, just a few. Please don’t use screenshots for this but text instead.

Comment: @DanielB Looks like they all have the same hardware id, see the update.

Comment: _ptun0901_ means this is (or rather was) a TAP-Win32 virtual network adapter. Did you install/update/uninstall any VPN software lately?

Comment: @DanielB yes, I did. I used VPN some time ago and then I uninstalled it. It was something like fortnite or FortniClient I can't remember exactly.

Comment: @Nelson installed drivers from CD, but nothing changed, see EDIT2.

Comment: At the end of the day, if you're not missing any functionalities, I would just ignore them. There are other ways to figure them out though, like using a Linux Live CD to see what they are being detected as, but in general it really doesn't matter too much.

Answer (score 2):

As per your information from the hardware IDs, the many “Unknown device” instances with the problems (yellow triangle) are TAP-Win32 virtual network interfaces. They are often used with VPN software like OpenVPN. You indicate you removed some VPN software lately. It apparently only removed the TAP-Win32 driver without removing the virtual network interfaces.

You already succeeded in removing all the broken virtual network interfaces.

The remaining device, “SMS/MMS”, is *not* broken and working as designed. The driver developer just neglected to define its device category, so it ended up in “Other devices”. This is not a problem in any way. If you want further information on this device, you should check its hardware IDs like before as well as the associated drivers on the “Driver” property page. Others on the internet associate this device with a paired Bluetooth phone.